# Increase nesting amount from user input

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple nested for loop system where there's one outer loop and then a unspecific number of very similar for loops nested in each other inside that one

So something like this

```
for (var outerindex = 0; outerindex < x; outerindex++ // Outer loop 
{        for (var innerindex1 = 0; innerindex1 < x; innerindex1++) //first innerLoop
    {
        sameFunction(); //
        for (var innerindex2 = 0; innerindex2 < x; innerindex2++) //second innerloop
        {
            sameFunction();
            for (var innerindex...
            {
                .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what i wanna do is to change the amount of innerloops by a variable. I guess I've got to use a function of some sort, but have idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion for that:

```js
function myLoop(i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    console.log('Inner function call!');
    myLoop(i - 1);
  } else {
    console.log('Final call');
  }
}

myLoop(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that via **recursion**.

Just call a function with the depth of for loops required, start a loop and call that function with depth - 1.

```js
function recurse(depth){
  if(depth <= 0) //Terminal statement to end the recursion
    return;
  for(var innerindex = 0; innerindex < depth; innerindex++){
     someFunction(depth,innerindex);
     recurse(depth -1);
  }
}
function someFunction(depth, innerindex){
  console.log('someFunction(depth: '+depth+', innerindex:'+innerindex+');');
}
recurse(3);
```

But for deep (e.g. > 100) `depth` it will eat all your stack and require a lot of memory.